# Sorting an array virtually, and storing the order only

Tags: c, sorting

I've got this code, but it isn't working as should. I need to virtually sort 'val' array in descending order, and store the order in 'order' array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_J_DIRS 4
#define FRAC_LEFT 0
#define FRAC_RIGHT 1
#define FRAC_FORWARD 2
#define FRAC_BACK 3
#define FIRST 0
#define SECOND 1
#define THIRD 2
#define FOURTH 3

struct iv
{
  int index;
  float value;
};

struct Fractions
{
  int order[NUM_J_DIRS];    //this is where we store order of 'val'
  float val[NUM_J_DIRS];    //once declared, this don't change
  int enabled[NUM_J_DIRS];  //once declared, this don't change
};

int main ()
{
  struct Fractions fractions;   
  struct iv iv[NUM_J_DIRS];
  fractions.val[FRAC_LEFT] = 0.1;
  fractions.val[FRAC_RIGHT] = 1.0;
  fractions.val[FRAC_FORWARD] = 1.0;
  fractions.val[FRAC_BACK] = 0.5;

  // populate iv from val 
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_J_DIRS; i++)
  {
    iv[i].index = i;
    iv[i].value = fractions.val[i];
  }

  // sort kv by value 
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_J_DIRS; i++)
  {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < NUM_J_DIRS; j++)
    {
      if (iv[i].value < iv[j].value)
      {
        struct iv temp = iv[i];
        iv[i] = iv[j];
        iv[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  // set order 
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_J_DIRS; i++)
  {
    fractions.order[iv[i].index] = i;
  }

  printf("order = %i, dir: %i, the value was: %f\n",
      FIRST, fractions.order[FIRST], fractions.val[fractions.order[FIRST]]);
  printf("order = %i, dir: %i, the value was: %f\n", 
      SECOND, fractions.order[SECOND], fractions.val[fractions.order[SECOND]]);
  printf("order = %i, dir: %i, the value was: %f\n", 
      THIRD, fractions.order[THIRD], fractions.val[fractions.order[THIRD]]);
  printf("order = %i, dir: %i, the value was: %f\n", 
      FOURTH, fractions.order[FOURTH], fractions.val[fractions.order[FOURTH]]);
  return 0;
}
```

outputs:
​

```
order = 0, dir: 3, the value was: 0.500000
order = 1, dir: 0, the value was: 0.100000
order = 2, dir: 1, the value was: 1.000000
order = 3, dir: 2, the value was: 1.000000
```

But should output:
​

```
order = 0, dir: 1, the value was: 1.000000
order = 1, dir: 2, the value was: 1.000000
order = 2, dir: 3, the value was: 0.500000
order = 3, dir: 0, the value was: 0.100000
```

​
The order between dir 1 and dir 2 is interchangeable since they have the same value. The order of direction of the same values is not important.

Code above should work imo, but doesn't. I have spent countless time figuring out why not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile and doing what I can. Formatting is bugging out.

Answer (score 2):

After sorting `iv`, the elements are in descending order by value, and each one carries a corresponding index into the `fractions.val` array.  So `iv[0].index` gives the index of the greatest element, `iv[1].index` gives the index of the next greatest, *etc*.  Therefore, when you read that out, you want the first element of `order` to take the `index` from the first element of `iv`, the second from the second, and so on. But that's not what this says:

> ```
>   // set order 
>   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_J_DIRS; i++)
>   {
>     fractions.order[iv[i].index] = i;
>   }
> ```

You have reversed the sense of `i` and `iv[i].index`.  What you actually want is

```
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_J_DIRS; i++) 
  {
    fractions.order[i] = iv[i].index;
  }
```

After I make that change, your program's output prints the values in descending order for me.

Comment: This is the best answer. It describes and corrects the bug in the code without introducing more code or pulling in libraries that are not otherwise needed.

Answer (score -2):

Declare this as your compare function:

```
int compareFunction(const void *p1, const void *p2, void *arg) {
    struct Fractions* f = (struct Fractions*)arg;
    int index1 = *(int*)p1;
    int index2 = *(int*)p2;
    if (f->val[index1] < f->val[index2]) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (f->val[index1] > f->val[index2]) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then to sort the "order" array based on the existing order of the "val" array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_J_DIRS; i++) {
    fractions.order[i] = i;    
}
qsort_r(fractions.order, NUM_J_DIRS, sizeof(int), &fractions);
```

You get `qsort_r` by adding a `#include <stdlib.h>` to the top of your source file.

Comment: I think `qsort_r` is a glibc function, but not part of the C standard?  Or was it added at some point?

Comment: No, `qsort_r()`is not part of standard C, nor even scheduled for C23.  Neither is it in POSIX.